# What's the point of Indirect Addressing?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-management

Indirect addressing allows you to reference memory locations, larger than the operand limit of a CPU.

i.e

```
1 | ADD 2 3
2 | #2
3 | *32000
...
32000 | #5
```

This will add memory location 2 and 3, 3 points to location 32000, so when it's evaluated, the effect is:

```
1 | ADD 2 32000
```

Even though 32000 may exceed the operand size limit.

My question is, why do this?

Why not simple have this:

```
1 | ADD 2 3
2 | #2
3 | #5
```

It saves time wasted on extra references to memory *and* space in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Indirect addressing is possible [without instructions that implement it explicitly](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/51448/30527). These instructions exist for our convenience, and not just for reaching a position that doesn't fit the address space of a direct addressing instruction (although this will become quite natural if your program is big enough): that's how we implement subprograms and arrays, for instance.

Comment: So, it'd be something automatically done by the compiler / os? Is its real use basically just a pointer, like in c++ etc as opposed to some memory work around?

Comment: Well, there usually *are* explicit instructions for indirect addressing, that a high-level language would use to implement its constructs. We wouldn't rely on any work around in the "real world". Pointers are an abstract extension of the concept of indirect addressing.